# How to view folium saved html on GitHub?

Tags: github, visualization, folium

I have saved a folium created map as html and put it on GitHub. But when I want to view it on the GitHub , it doesn't show the map but only show as below.[image]

I tried to use https://htmlpreview.github.io/

and pasted

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaiyungtan/challenge-data-analysis/master/Visualisation/average_price_per_sqm_belgium_apartment.html to preview...

But it didn't work.

Anyone knows how to view it from Github?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems https://htmlpreview.github.io/ doesn't load all the JS scripts from your page. I think the easiest way to serve your file is to activate the Github Pages on your repo:

Go to settings :

[image: Github page settings]

Select master branch in your case, click Save and go to :

https://kaiyungtan.github.io/challenge-data-analysis/Visualisation/average_price_per_sqm_belgium_apartment.html

For example, I've forked your repo and activated Github page, it shows :

https://bertrandmartel-bot.github.io/challenge-data-analysis/Visualisation/average_price_per_sqm_belgium_apartment.html

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. Much appreciated